# Chrome found DOM error 2 elements Non-Unique ID with input type password

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

2 Input Type Password HTML Tag I m using in my form it give me error non-unique id. I have given the different id to two different  tag

MY code

```
 <div id="Authdialog-message" title="Authorization" style="display: none">
    <label>PassWord :</label>
    <input id="AuthPwD"  type="password" name="Pwd" class="TextBxFormat"  style="width: 200px; margin-left: 5px;">
 </div>

 <div id="AdminstRemark" title="Add Remark" style="display: none">
    <label>PassWord </label>
    <input id="RmkAuthPwD" type="password" name="Pwd1" class="TextBxFormat Mandatory" style="width: 200px; margin-left: 5px;">
 </div>
```

But when i ucomment this two line of code below

```
<input id="AuthPwD"  type="password" name="Pwd" class="TextBxFormat"   
                              style="width: 200px; margin-left: 5px;">
<input id="RmkAuthPwD" type="password" name="Pwd1" class="TextBxFormat Mandatory" 
                             style="width: 200px; margin-left: 5px;">
```

the error disappear

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some of your code (properly formatted)? It would be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Comment one by one and make a search in the IDE for each id you have in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

It can be helpful for you to find non-unique id on your page.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id=test]');
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('[id=test]');
```

Just console.log the non-unique id this way:

```
console.log( $('[id=hello]')); // hello - your non-unique id
```